# JScript 'import' syntax for ASP classic

Tags: javascript, asp-classic, import

I'm using an ASP "classic" server, with JavaScript as the language engine, specified by the directive:

```
<%@LANGUAGE='JAVASCRIPT'%>
```

I've noticed that `import' seems to be a keyword.

```
Technical Information (for support personnel)

    * Error Type:
      Microsoft JScript compilation (0x800A03F2)
      Expected identifier
      /Default.asp, line 4, column 4
      var import = 'whut'
      ---^
```

How is the `import' keyword used, if at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like in most programming languages, certain keywords are reserved. Javascript is a bit special since it reserves more keywords than are implemented in the language. Import is one of those words. Other examples are 'private' and 'void', though they are not implemented in the current releases.

Comment: void is implemented, albeit not really usefull.

Answer (score 2):

From [here](http://www.devguru.com/Technologies/Ecmascript/Quickref/import.html):

> The **import** statement allows a script
> to import properties, functions and
> objects exported by a signed script.
> The following code imports the 'wine'
> and 'beer' properties of the object
> 'drinks' provided they have been made
> available by an exporting script
> (compare the export statement):
>
> **Code**: i`mport drinks.beer, drinks.wine;`
>
> NOTE:   Any exported script must be
> loaded into a window, frame or layer
> before it can be imported and used.

Comment: Thanks, Andrew. I have tried to use this syntax with a made up export, but it seems to still show a syntax error:

Error Type:
Microsoft JScript compilation (0x800A03EA)
Syntax error
/Default.asp, line 4
import drinks.beer, drinks.wine;

I would not expect a syntax error here. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

import is a reserved word in js, but I think it is only actually used in JScript.NET and ActionScript.

Answer (score 0):

The full list of reserved words for JScript (although many are not used in the language) are:

```
abstract, boolean, break, byte, case, catch, char, class, const, continue, debugger,
default, delete, do, double, else, enum, export, extends, false, final, finally,
float, for, function, goto, if, implements, import, in, instanceof, int, interface,
long, native, new, null, package, private, protected, public, return, short, static,
super, switch, synchronized, this, throw, throws, transient, true, try, typeof, var,
volatile, void, while, with
```

Hope this helps.